# SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' main.js (143651,12) Error in I.E-11 after updating laravel mix version from 2.0 to 4.0.14

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, webpack-4, laravel-mix, vue-cli-3

I have created a vuejs template with laravel integration. On creating project with vue-laravel, by default the laravel-mix version is 2.0 and at that time my project is running well in all browsers. But now I am updating version of laravel-mix from 2.0 to 4.0.14. On updating it, blank screen should be display on I.E browser. As I am new in vue+laravel and not enough knowledge about it. I am trying to resolve this issue by following many links but did't get the results. Please anyone knows how it should be possible to run vue+laravel project on IE and what changes are required.

> Screenshot of IE browser console:

[image]

Here is my webpack.mix.js file code:

```
//webpack.mix.js

let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
 mix.autoload({
  'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
 })

mix.js('resources/js/main.js', 'public/js');
```

Here is my development dependencies in package.json file:

```
// package.json
"devDependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18",
  "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
  "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "laravel-mix": "^4.0.14",
  "lodash": "^4.17.11",
  "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
  "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "vue": "^2.5.19",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.22"
}
```

.babelrc file code:

```
//.babelrc
{
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

If anyone needs more info let me know. Thanks!

Comment: did you made sure you updated all you dependecies asswel?

Comment: yes i  have updated all dependencies

Answer (score -1):

for IE, you need to install and include polyfill as well.

`npm install --save @babel/polyfill`

Comment: yes i have installed babel-pollyfill also but not get the required result

Comment: did you include polyfill ? either in the HTML or with webpack ?

Comment: yes , i have tried using Html and webpack. Can you please tell me where should I add and what are the steps to include pollyfilll. May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Well i have imported babel-pollyfill in main.js on top of all import statements.

Comment: then I am no help to you then, IE is a very tricky thing to work with ... all I know is that you need to ask polyfill